# PHP session_start() usage

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I use session_start() in my code i have the session setup properly and when I run the code and log in it keeps me logged in and everything works properly, but when I add HTML underneath the PHP code located at the top of the page and refresh it (while logged in) it logged me out?

My Code Without HTML

Core file

```
ob_start();
session_start();

function loggedin() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])&&!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
        require 'connect.inc.php';
    require 'core.php';
    include 'main_login.inc.php';

        if (loggedin()) {
        $dir = $user_name;
        if($handle = @opendir($dir)) {
            if($handle2 = @opendir($dir.'/docs')){
                //If Logged In And Users File Exists: Load Page

            }
        } else {
            // If Users File Does Not Exist: Create User File
            @mkdir($user_name, 0755, true);
            // Create Docs
            @mkdir($user_name.'/docs', 0755, true);
        }
    } else {
        // If User Is Not Logged: Redirect To Jamie Co Home
        @header('Location: http://www.jamieco.ca');
}
?>
```

My code with HTML (Non-working code)

```
    <?php
    require_once 'connect.inc.php';
    require_once 'core.php';
    include 'main_login.inc.php';

        if (loggedin()) {
        $dir = $user_name;
        if($handle = @opendir($dir)) {
            if($handle2 = @opendir($dir.'/docs')){
                //If Logged In And Users File Exists: Load Page

            }
        } else {
            // If Users File Does Not Exist: Create User File
            @mkdir($user_name, 0755, true);
            // Create Docs
            @mkdir($user_name.'/docs', 0755, true);
        }
    } else {
        // If User Is Not Logged: Redirect To Jamie Co Home
        @header('Location: #');
}
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <header>

    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href = "clients.html">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href = "login.html">Sign In</a></li>
    <li><a href = "contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    <div id = "clear" />

    <div id = "big_wrapper">
    <div id = "wrapper">
    <br><br>
    <!-- Logged In Stuff Goes Here -->

    <div id = "user_options">
    <ul>
    <li><?php echo 'Welcome, '.$first_name.' '.$last_name.'<br><br>'; ?></li>
    <li><a href = "logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <?php echo 'Welcome Back '.$first_name; ?>
    <br><br>

    <table border = "1" cellspacing = "5" id = "files">
    <tr><td colspan = "7">File Handling</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td>File Name:</td>
    <td>File Size:</td>
    <td>File Type:</td>
    <td>Security Level:</td>
    <td colspan = "3">Actions:</td>
    </tr>

    <?php   

            $dir = $user_name.'/docs/';
            if($handle = @opendir($dir)) {
            while($file = @readdir($handle)) {
                if($file!='.'&&$file!='..') {
                    echo '<tr><td><a href = "'.$user_name.'/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></td>';
                        $name = $dir.$file;
                        $size = filesize($dir.$file);
                        $type = substr($name, strrpos($name, '.')+1);
                        echo '<td>'.$size.' Bytes'.'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$type.'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$file_grade.'</td>';
                        echo '<td><a href = "'.$dir.$file.'">'.'Download'.'</a></td>';
                        echo '<td><a href = "#">'.'Rename'.'</a></td>';
                        echo '<td><a href = "#">'.'Delete'.'</a></td>';
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <br><br>

    <!-- Stuff Here -->

    <br><br>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Am I being blind? I don't see `session_start()` anywhere :S You want that as the very very first thing in your code after `<?php`

Comment: *sidenote:* is there any reason you use both `require` and `include`? Suggest to use `require_once`, if your file is planned to be included once, as it will throw error instead of warning (and will stop running the codes after)

Comment: *sidenote:* remember to call `exit;` after `header("Location: $url");` if it is not the last line

Comment: Timmy no you are not blind the session start is in the `require core.php` file at the top of the page

Comment: So many error suppressions..

Comment: *sidenote:* it is **not** suggested to suppress error by prefix functions by `@`. You just hide the errors instead of handling the errors. In short, remove all `@`.

Comment: @NewEurope how can we know if there is any `session_start()` in your `core.php`? Timmy is right.

Comment: Chances are if you stop suppressing the errors, PHP will tell you what's wrong

Comment: *sidenote:* (Aw... lots of errors in code) You used HTML5 doctype, but you are using deprecated table attribute `border`, `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` and you omitted `<head>`. Also, recommend to replace `<br><br>` with CSS position adjustments.

Comment: Normally on other sites I like to call myself `/etc/passwd` or `<script src=http://www.example.com/malicious-code.js</script>` how would you handle this on your site?

Comment: hard to troubleshoot what you can't see!

Comment: if its any consolation i added the core.php containing the `session_start()`

Comment: `session_start()` function must place before your session works. All make sure to call it at once of all code.

Careful with `require` and `include`. Why not is `require_once` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. I changed the session to a token, not sure why this works but it does!